# Android: why isn't setPadding being respected?

Tags: android

I am trying to set the background of a Button to a PaintDrawable which I am creating in code.  This works pretty well, but my Button appears larger than an android.view.Button.

In the below image, the first Button is an instance of MyButton, the second button is an instance of android.widget.Button.

I tried both setting the padding on the PaintDrawable and MyButton, but neither has any noticeable effect.

[image]

```
public class MyButton extends Button
{
    PaintDrawable drawable = null; 

    public ColorButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        drawable = new PaintDrawable();
        drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawable.setCornerRadius(1);

        //neither of these seem to do anything?
        drawable.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

        setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        //set gradient in here, because getWidth/getHeight are useless prior to this
        drawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(getMeasuredWidth()/2, 0, getMeasuredWidth()/2, getMeasuredHeight(), Color.WHITE, Color.GRAY, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the difference between padding and margins

Padding determines how much "padding" is on the inside of your container.
Margins determine how much space to leave around the outside of your container.

Since you are setting the padding on an empty container you should see no visible results. 
If you had something inside your container you may notice it getting squished as you increase your values

Try this in your code. It will only work on the button (your parent class)

```
//set your fill values to whatever you want
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
setLayoutParams(lp);
```